# Does kubernetes have a default registry?

Tags: kubernetes, registry

For example ,does kubernetes cluster have a default registry inside the cluster ?

- is it possible to deploy image from local to public cluster without a registry like docker.io
- it sounds stupid but is there a way to "embed" image inside yaml file without pull mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

`does kubernetes cluster have a default registry inside the cluster ?`

Inside the cluster - No. Docker public registry is the default when you don't specify a registry as part of your image URI.

`is it possible to deploy image from local to public cluster without a regitry like docker.io`

You can export local image and import into your public cluster, eg. `docker save --output busybox.tar busybox`, `docker load -i <exported image>`

`is there a way to "embed" image inside yaml file without pull mechanism?`

No.

Comment: You can't really use `docker load` in Kubernetes.  You'd have to repeat it on every single node, including when one is automatically created by the cluster autoscaler, or else you'll get an ImagePullBackOff error.

Comment: `You can't really use docker load in Kubernetes` - Not true. eg. place the image loading logic in instance startup script, doesn't matter if cluster autoscaler or you spin up the node.